# In a scale-free network, how does the global clustering coefficient scales with the number of nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, network

The title pretty much says it all. I have a directed graph with $n$ nodes such that the distribution of degrees follows a power law with exponent $\alpha$. If I double $n$, what happens to the [global clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) of the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I found an answer. According to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1997.pdf) the global clustering coefficient for a scale-free graph declines at rate $n^{-\frac{\left(\alpha-2\right)^2}{2\alpha}}$ where $\alpha$ is the power law exponent of the degree distribution.